# proving C2 continuity given closed spline constraints

Tags: continuity, spline

Given the closed spline's constraints as below

$$P(0) = P_k  $$
$$P(1) = P_{k+1}$$
$$P''(0) = P_{k-1} - 2P_{k}+P_{k+1}$$ 
$$P''(1) = P_{k} - 2P_{k+1}+P_{k+2}$$

How do I prove that this spline satisfies $C_2$ continuity between adjacent segments?

Graphically, I understand how $C_2$ continuity looks like, but when it comes to proves I really have no idea where to start.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the definition of spline here? If it is defined just as being a cubic having the right values and derivatives at the endpoints, then it would seem it would be automatically $C_2$ (and more) at any point strictly between endpoints. When two successive ones are linked, it seems the endpoint conditions will make the piecewise result $C_2$ at the joining points also.

Comment: Hi, I actually made a mistake in my question. I am given the second derivative of P. Given this information, can I just say that C2 continuity exists since we are given the second derivatives, and both follow the same pattern as p?

Comment: What is the form of the spline? That is, maybe it is an undetermined cubic, like $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ and one must determine the coefficients. Or maybe it's of higher degree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the spline's second derivative at the right hand side and left hand side of the segment joint are the same, then the spline has C2 continuity at the segment joint. So, to prove it, you will have to find the 2nd derivative of the spline from the first segment at parameter t, then find the 2nd derivative of the spline from the next segment at the same parameter t. If they are the same, then the spline has C2 continuity at parameter t.